# Loop an SP2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a list that contains all active employees using a person of group column. I am trying to create a workflow that would check if the employee is still active at intervals and if no longer active delete the item.

[image: Screen Shot]

So far I have it set to check active status. If valid it pauses, Else it deletes. I just cannot get it to loop after the pause.

Comment: You need to schedule this workflow. The approach you're following is wrong. Check : http://blogs.askcts.com/2013/05/14/creating-a-timed-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: This is a great blog post. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the Central Administration for the second half of his instructions.

Comment: I don't think there is a need of editing the timer job settings or clicking on run now. Instead of seeing the results immediately, you'll have to wait for a while. Even without that retention will work just fine.

Comment: Workflow is not suitable in this situation. Write a console application or PowerShell script that does this check and add it as a WINDOWS schedule task. If you use CSOM, the scheduled task even does not have to be on the same machine as the SharePoint server.

Answer (score 1):

Create a field named "NextCheck" and a field named "CheckField". Create a workflow to run when item has created or edited and pause until the "NextCheck" date as come. After this, set the field "CheckField" to true. Create another workflow to run when item has edited and check if the "CheckField" is true. If it was, verify the user and if is valid, set the "NextCheck" to today + 30 days.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be looping the workflow for me. Unfortunately, the rest of the workflow is not working for me but that is an unrelated problem. It is not deleting inactive users. I've found that for past employees although their username is no longer valid the site still recognizes them as a "Valid SharePoint User" because their info is cached on the server. :(

Comment: But why you need to delete them? It's for not appear in a form user field?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop sharepoint 2010 workflows in an easy manner, are you in a 2013 environment, if so you can use 2013 workflow.

Otherwise the path you will have to take is one of the following:

1. Use a 3rd party workflow tool (Nintex, K2)
2. Make 2 lists and have the workflows talk to each other, basically you will have the workflow create and update items between the 2 lists, I have done this before and it will work, you just need to have the items talk to each other with GUIDs and then keep track of a loop counter and add alot of logic. This can get very complex.

Comment: And in some instances it has been seen that this only works for about 5 loops and stops.